# Wget: Change title

Tags: batch-file, wget, title

I'm working with Batch and Wget.exe . The kind of "problem" is that wget changes the title to wget and URL. Is there any command or something to change the program's title?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean you like to set exact output file name?

Comment: `title` is the command to change the title (see `title /?`). Although it can't prevent it to be changed by wget.

Comment: `wget -q` (quiet mode) keeps current title, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use quiet parameter.

```
wget.exe -q "http://www.google.com/test.zip" >NUL
```